# Efficient solution to the set grouping problem

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures, dynamic-programming, greedy

Problem Statement:

> We are given N number of sets conataining atmost M elements each. We have to merge those sets in the following way:-
> We can merge(union) 2 sets to create a 2 member group.
> We can merge(union) 3 sets to create a 3 member group.
> We can merge(union) 4 sets to create a 4 member group.
> One set can be a member of only one group (either 2 member, 3 member or 4 member group).
> Max number of 2 member groups is n2, max number of 3 member groups is n3 and likewise n4. Every set is not necessarily merged, we can keep skip some sets if that maximizes our goal.
> we define the size of a formed group as number of defferent elements in it.
>
> Now our goal is to maximize the sum of squares of sizes of all groups.
>
> Constraints:
>
> `1<=N<=10**5`
>
> `1<=M<=10**6`
>
> `0<=n2,n3,n4<=5*10**4`

Example:

> We are given five sets : `{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{2,4,7},{6,5,4},{6,7}` and `0<=n2,n3,n4<=3`. Note that 2nd and 4th sets are identical as they are having same elements. But no set is having duplicate elements within it.

> Now the solution to this example comprises of merging 2nd and 5th set to produce a 2 member group `{4,5,6} + {7,6} = {4,5,6,7}` and merging the rest of three sets to give a 3 member group `{1,2,3} + {2,4,7} + {6,5,4} = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` . This merging produces sum of squares of sizes `s = 4**2 + 7**2 = 65` as our final result. Not that any other combination of grouping produces less sum of squares of sizes.

I can only see the brute force method which takes a lot of running time as there are too many of all possible combinations.

My Solution ( which is not complete and open for suggestions):

> Lets assign a group number to each set which will help us keeping the track of which set is merged into which group. If a set is assigned number `0` , it means this set is not merged into any group. If a set is assigned a number in the range `[1,n2]` (both limits inclusive) , it means this set is merged into a 2 member group ( and also tells about which 2 member group this set is merged into). If a set is assigned a number in the range `[n2+1,n2+n3]` (both limits inclusive) , tells that this set is merged into a 3 member group. And likewise a set can be assigned a number in the range `[n2+n3+1,n2+n3+n4]`.

> Now we can maintain a 2 dimensional dp as follow.
> `Dp[i]` is a list of `i elements` telling us how the first `i` sets are grouped. Thus `dp[i][j]` is the group number assigned to `jth` set when first `i` sets are iterated.
> `dp[i]` can be calculated as follow.
> ith set can be grouped into either

> 2 member group

> or 3 member group

> or 4 member group

> or not grouped in any group

> We can iterate through each possibility and use the one which maximizes our goal ( but still not sure how).

Comment: What have you attempted so far? (Please see [ask].)

Comment: Are all the elements different or can some occur more than once given that they start in different sets? Does your union remove duplicities or are the duplicates blocking space for non-duplicates? Example could be helpful :-).

Comment: @Shamis  one element can occur in different sets. Union remove duplicate items. Let me edit the question to provide an example.

Comment: @shamis I have updated the question with an example, let me know if you want any further clarity on the problem statement.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy, please look into the updated question. I am trying to implement a dynamic programming solution but haven't succeeded yet.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really the place for free algorithm design.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy then which is?

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. I'll look into it. While SO isn't site for free algorithm design, it is a place to *consult* about the algorithms. And the fact that the OP was engaged enough to edit & clarify the question several times is enough for me :-). Not promising a result though, just that I'll look deeper. Cheers and have a good time asking.

Comment: @Shamis Thank you very much. Actually I am struggling from a couple of weeks to solve this problem, but unable to find anything. Thanks for your valuable time. It looks to me that there may be a greedy solution which comprises of minimizing the shared elements and prioritizing the larger groups over smaller ones.

Comment: Just a quick one: in your example, grouping {1,2,3}{4,5,6}{6,7} and {4,5,6}{2,4,7} is actually better with the resulting sum of 74. However other than that I'm currently joining your stuck status since so far I can't see past brute force with some minor pruning - which as far as I counted probably isn't enough. Yare yare. As for the grouping for the largest groups while minimizing the shared elements might not work, I keep finding counter examples possible in some cases.

Comment: Like when {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3, 5} are not worth to be merged(16 + 16 vs 25) while if we add another sufficiently large set to the mix {6,7,8,9,10} then merging all together suddenly becomes worth it: 100 vs 16 + 81 (case when we merge 2 and leave one out to minimize overlap). It usually just depends on a breaking point and the overlap vs non-overlap count. I recall meeting something similar years ago, but I can't remember well enough. :-/

Comment: @shamis Yeah , looks like my example is not having optimal solution, the grouping combination you mentioned is producing a better result. This problem is reasonably very hard. I will look into "It usually just depends on a breaking point and the overlap vs non-overlap count" and see if I can establish some logic based on it. Thanks again for giving your precious time , Have a good day!